# vb.net reconnecting lost connection automatically to mysql server

Tags: vb.net-2010

Any idea on reconnecting lost connection automatically using vb.net (windows form) to mysql server.

I am planning to develop an application. To be specific, it is a timer for an internet cafe.

The case is if the server downloaded some updates and need to restart, the client pc will reconnect automatically when the server boot up. Any idea? Thanks

I'm using this code to connect:

```
Dim DatabaseName As String = "xxx"
Dim server As String = "xxx"
Dim userName As String = "xxx"
Dim password As String = "xxx"
If Not conn Is Nothing Then conn.Close()
conn.ConnectionString = String.Format("server={0}; user id={1}; password={2}; database={3}; pooling=false", server, userName, password, DatabaseName)
        Try
            conn.Open()
            MsgBox("Connected")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        conn.Close()
```

Comment: Your question and problem are not very clear. Please explain more.

Comment: thanks. my problem is about reconnecting lost connection automatically. Can I use timer or should I use a socket connection?